# Android: recording audio using MediaRecorder - file doesnt play

Tags: android, audio, mediarecorder

i´ve implemented the sample Code direct from Google using [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder.html)

Also I have added some properties and set the filetype to ".mp3" (I know that it doesnt create a real mp3, but ".3gp" doesnt make sence to me either, I´m recording Audio not Video..)

Now my Problem is that, if I want to Play the file, it does nothing (0:00 sec). I checked the properties on the file, it fills up space on the storage.

ADDITIONAL:

Anyway I want to implement a visual Feedback while recording. [Horizon](https://github.com/Yalantis/Horizon) seems to be the only good looking lib. But using Horizon you have to feed it with the buffer from Audiorecorder, which is not possible with MediaRecoder. Does anybody know a good looking lib that visualizes currently recording audio with MediaRecorder?

Thank you very much

```
private void startRecording() {
    if(this.mRecorder != null)
        return;

    String fileToWrite = this.ProjectDirPath + File.separator + GetToday() + this.fileTpye;

    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(fileToWrite);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.HE_AAC);
    mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(16000);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(44100);
    mRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);

    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("startRecording()", "prepare() failed");
    }

    initRecorder();
    mRecorder.start();
    isRecording = true;
}



private void stopRecording() {
    if(this.mRecorder == null)
        return;
    else{
        try{
            mRecorder.stop();
            mRecorder.release();
            mRecorder = null;
            isRecording = false;
            this.updateListView();
        } catch(Exception e){
            mRecorder = null;
            isRecording = false;
        }
    }
}

public static String GetToday(){
    Date presentTime_Date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    return dateFormat.format(presentTime_Date);
}
```

Permissions are set in the manifest and at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found myself one good lib.

https://github.com/adrielcafe/AndroidAudioRecorder?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=4099